# Trusting users with route parameter and hidden input values

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.8

I'm creating a school management system software with laravel, this project happens to be my first big project, to be used commercially. And no one is supervising the work (so you see I really need advice here). So the problem I have is when to trust user inputs and when to check if a model exist before using it in another table. for example checking if a 'student_id' exists in the 'users' table before inserting the student_id in an 'attendances' table. This question also applies to every other time i want to persist a model in other tables. As illustration I have brought out a part of the code for taking students attendace.

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('daily.attendance')}}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="section_id" value="{{$section_id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="semester_id" value="{{$semester_id}}">
@foreach ($sections as $section)

 @foreach ($section->users as $student)      
            <input type="checkbox" name = "present[]" value = "{{$student->id}}" class = "present">
            <input type="hidden" name = "students[]" value = "{{$student->id}}"> 
 @endforeach

 @endforeach
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >{{ __('take attendance') }}</button>      
</form>
```

php

```
public static function takeStudentDailyAttendance($request){

        $presentStudents = ( isset($request->present) ) ? $request->present : [] ;
        $dataForPresent = collect( $request->except(['present' , 'students']) )->merge(['status' => 1 , 'takenBy_id' => Auth::user()->id])->toArray();
        $dataForAbsent = collect( $request->except(['present' , 'students']) )->merge(['status' => 0 , 'takenBy_id' => Auth::user()->id])->toArray();

        DB::transaction(function () use ($request , $dataForPresent , $dataForAbsent , $presentStudents) {

            foreach($request->students as $student_id){
                if( in_array($student_id , $presentStudents) ){

                    $dataForPresent['student_id'] = $student_id; 
                    StudentDailyAttendance::create($dataForPresent);

                }else{
                    $dataForAbsent['student_id'] = $student_id;
                    StudentDailyAttendance::create($dataForAbsent);
                } 
            }
        });
    }
```

So, even though I used hidden input for $section_id and $semester_id, I know the user (admin) can change those values by using his browser console, then send the form. Imagine the admin deliberately or accidentally ( the route that displays the for is like this `"daily/student/section/{section_id}')`  changes the $section_id or the $semester_id to values which doesn't correspond to any model in the sections table and Semesters table. Boom!!! he or she (the admin) has taken attendance of a section or semester that doesn't even exist, and it is not good as it has flawed the integrity of the database. so the question is should I trust the admin or should I check for the existence of the $section_id and $semester_id in their corresponding tables before inserting into the 'attendances' table (doing this will also increase the time for the script to end).
Also looking at the php code the student_id values can also be tampered form the html, and you see the code loops through arrays of students marked present and students marked absent, should i also check if the $student_id exists in the 'users' table before taking attendance (doing this will also increase the time for the script to end)  or should I also trust the admin?

Comment: Though this question is asking for an opinion (which stackoverflow is not intended for), I say, never trust the user. It can be an admin but also an attacker that deliberately creates compromises in your code or it could be a bug on your side that would mess with the database if you don't properly check for existence and also access to each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule always says never trust the user especialy when speaking about data entigrity. I'd suggest try laravel's validaton approach:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-exists

However if performance is your first concern, I'd cache the userIds and sectionIds in a redis hash for sometime when the attendence page is first requested and then check if for example student_id is in the cached user_ids
If you want to have a look at Laravel's caching:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache